# Phonegap 2.9.0 developing in Xcode: Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function in file

Tags: jquery, xcode, jquery-mobile, cordova

I keeping getting a debug error code outputting to the Xcode console when I try and click on the row in question and kick off the event listener.

Error Message in full (long file path removed to keep it clean):

> Error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function in file:///Users/....../index.js at line 1339

*1339 is first line of code block displayed.*

**Code:**

```
        $("#contact-list").on("click", "a", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var me = this;
        console.log('The event listener is working');

        var phoneNumber = me.attr('id').text();
        console.log('phoneNumber is being sent');
        if (phoneNumber.substr(0, 1) == '+') {
            phoneNumber = me.userExitCode + phoneNumber.substr(1);
        }
        phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

        var data = {
            'name': me.children('h3').val(),
            'phone_number': phoneNumber,
            'part': 'contact'
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var phoneNumber = me.attr('id').text();
```

Will not work. If your intentions were to grab the id of me element,

```
var phoneNumber = $(me).attr('id');
```

1. I wrapped your `me` with $ (because `me` is `this`, jQuery expects `$(this)`
2. I removed `text()` function call, because `attr` itself will return text.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have JQuery included? If your version of JQuery is newer than 1.7, than the function "live" has been deprecated for "on".

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Sources:

-http://api.jquery.com/live/

-http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the multiple comments! I've updated the code but still seem to be getting an error from this line: var phoneNumber = me.attr('id').text();    Any thoughts?

Comment: Is your JQuery included before your index.js file? Did you include the entire Click function in your code above?? The code you posted above doesn't show the closing brackets for your click function. Also, have you tried just the normal jquery click function? http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: In JQuery, you can access "this" by using **$(this)**